# Criar uma rotina dentro de uma aplicação asp net em c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho que rodar um método no meu projeto `ASP.Net`, fiz uma tela para que eu selecione um `Excel` e um método para que sejam feitas as tratativa e inserções no banco, só que esse método vai ter que ser rodado diariamente, alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer isso?

PS.: Sou leigo no ambiente `ASP.Net`

Comment: Você quer dizer que o método tem que ser chamado diariamente sem interação do usuário?

Comment: Onde a aplicação vai ficar hospedada?

Comment: Isso @MarcusVinicius.

Comment: Atualmente está na localweb @CiganoMorrisonMendez , mas já consegui um servidor próprio para hospedar a aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Nao é aconselhável agendar tarefas dentro duma aplicação ASP.NET.

O AppDomain pode ser reciclado a qualquer momento, e quando isso acontece, todas as threads que não estiverem ligadas ao processamento duma request vão ser abortadas. Por outras palavras, a tua tarefa agendada pode ser abortada a qualquer momento, resultando em erros e estado inconsistente.

Mais detalhes em: [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/).

Eu aconselho criar uma nova console application, e depois usar o [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) para escolher a periocidade/frequência com que deve ser invocada.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um serviço **GRATUITO** chamado [A Trigger](https://atrigger.com/), no qual você se cadastra e pode agendar chamadas para um WebService. Você pode agendar direto pelo painel de controle do prórprio site ou usar uma library que te dá os mesmo recursos programaticamente. Você pode, por código, agendar, pausar e cancelar agendamentos de chamada ao seu web service. Aqui um exemplo de como agendar via código C#:

Baixe a biblioteca via nuget:

```
Install-Package ATrigger
```

---

Configure a chamada da rotina:

```
using ATriggerLib;

....
ATrigger.Initialize("YOUR_APIKey", "YOUR_APISecret"); // obtenha a APIKEY e o APISecret se cadastrando no site
// crie um dicionário com tags que serão usadas para identificar o seu serviço,
Dictionary<string, string> tags = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tags.Add("type", "teste");

// configura a chamada da rotina uma vez ao dia
ATrigger.Client.doCreate(TimeQuantity.Day(), "1", "http://www.examplo.com.br/rotina?algumacoisa", tags);
```

Se quiser interromper o agendamento da chamada, utilize:

```
ATrigger.Client.doDelete(tags);
```

Ou para somente pausar/retomar o agendamento:

```
 // pausar
 ATrigger.Client.doPause(tags);
 // retomar
 ATrigger.Client.doResume(tags);
```

Leia mais [aqui](http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/13/library-net).

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!!!!